# similar strings out of many strings

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm

I have a large number of strings say N , from which i have to find out sets of similar strings.
example :

Input :
`programmable

stackover

tree

stackoverflow

trie

program

oddoneout`

Output:

`set 1:

programmable

program`

`set 2:

stackoverflow

stackover`

`set 3:

tree

trie`

`set 4:

oddoneout`

So , what should be efficient `algorithm` (in both space and time ) ?

1) using levenshtein distance is good way but we still have to search all n-1 strings for each string.

2) using trie can be good (as far as prefix is concerned) but not the best way as it can't compare strings like al`g`orithm  and  al`q`kefgjwfjfwfkvfvjs , which are not at all similar.

`similarity of 2 strings:

1) the less the number of different characters in both , more similar are they

2)one string can be converted/transformed into another by just changing , adding some characters in one or both strings`
Please share your views.

please don't post about external softwares etc..

Comment: What is the definition of similarity of strings ?

Comment: So, are the words `clever` and `smart` similar? You must define the `similarity of the strings`

Comment: @Rndm @ Rondogiannis Aristophanes   added meaning of similarity

Comment: Not trivial: If the weather is no good, the wether migth think whether it should feel well or not.

Comment: Some variation on the Soundex algorithm, maybe?

Comment: @RontogiannisAristofanis: Good one. And more, is "clever" more similar to "smart" than "stack" is to "stackoverflow"? (the former differ by 6 characters, the latter by 8 characters...).

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a point based system where each matching character scores 1, lets say, and other similar sounding letters (or letters close to it on the keyboard or close phonetic sounds get 0.5 or something) and others get zero that don't match.

So, you have `tree` and you want to find similar words.

`program` scores 1 because only the r matches in the right place.

`trie` gets 3.

Maybe something like `trwe` gets 3.5, for example.

But then you look at the scores with a tolerance. That tolerance would dictate how close you want it to be.

But it really does depend on what it is you are looking for.

And this is a total out of the air thing, so not sure how well it would work. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints about similarity of 2 strings sounds like the edit distance problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

You can obtain the minimum edit distance between two strings by an Dynamic Programming Algorithm in O(NxM) where N and M are the length of each string.

You can set a threshold number that say "how similar have to be your strings", after setting this number, you can try an all against all algorithm that to check every possible minimum edit distance between all strings. I think you can make the sets with that information

If you know that the strings in your problem will be short (say length < 100), this  approach could be a good solution.

**Edit:**

Let K be the number of strings you want to clasify in sets and let N be the length avarage of your strings. The complexity of the algorithm that I'm proposing is O((K^2)x(N^2)).

(that's why we want N to be a small number)